# Binary mistake using find vector

Tags: c++

```
while (currentNode != endNode)
 {

   nextNode = path[currentNode][endNode];
  nextNode1 = path[currentNode][nextNode];
   takeRoute.x = nextNode1;
    route.push_back(takeRoute);
   routeiterator= find(route.begin(), route.end(),nextNode);
  if(routeiterator!=route.end())
    {
      takeRoute.x = nextNode;
      route.push_back(takeRoute);
     }

    currentNode = nextNode;

  }
```

binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'Node7' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
Что я делаю не так ?
Node7 это точка , потому что я использую "struct"
и `vector<Node7>route`

Comment: Приведите [mcve] чтобы можно было понять Вашу проблему более точно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для сравнения экземпляров пользовательских классов (а структура это тоже самое) через `==` нужно реализовать перегрузку этого оператора:

```
bool operator== (const Node& lhs, const Node& rhs) {
    // сравниваем, например, почленно и возвращаем true для равных объектов, 
    // и false для разных.
}
```

Как вариант, в теле оператора сравнения можно использовать `memcmp`, но это не всегда приемлимо.

В данном примере показана реализация через свободную (не член класса) функцию. Если реализовать в качестве члена, то сигнатура будет следующей:

```
struct Node {
    bool operator== (const Node& rhs) const;
};
```

Но лучше отдать предпочтения свободной функции, в таком случае можно будет сравнивать `Node` также и с объектами, которые могут быть неявно преобразованы в `Node` и при этом стоять слева от знака `==`.

Comment: 'struct CompareNodes
 {

  bool operator()(Node7&a, Node7&b)
  {
                         if(a.x==b.x) return false;
   else
  }
 } alreadyCompareNodes.. А потом в код вместо NextNode , вставить alreadyCompareNodes.    Верно? Извините за оформление

Comment: Не работает .. Я не могу понять , что потом мне добавлять в find вектора?